# How do I unmount (eject) a USB stick from the command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, umount

On Linux I can unmount a device with `umount` or `eject`. On Mac you can use `diskutil`. Is there a way to unmount devices so that they can be safely removed on Windows?

Comment: Side note about "on Linux I can unmount a device with `umount`": No, with `umount` you unmount a *filesystem*. After `umount` the block device is still available, you can see it in the output of `lsblk`, it can still be read or written to. I/O operations that use the block device directly (as opposed to using the filesystem) can still happen, be cached or whatever. If you are sure there are no write operations like this then `umount` is usually enough, but in general the right command before physically unplugging a USB stick is `eject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e680f48f-30f0-44bb-8289-3eb09e89a226/command-line-to-quotsafely-remove-a-usb-drivequot):

> ... the answer is that there isn't one. No Microsoft-only command can eject a usb drive just like "Safely Remove Hardware" does it.

It even links to [this other article](https://askleo.com/is_there_a_way_to_safely_remove_hardware_from_a_batch_file) that discusses the use of a Microsoft command line tool named [`devcon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)

*There are some warnings: `devcon` doesn't just remove/eject the media in the drive, it removes/ejects the drive itself -- you might need to reinstall the hardware, unplug and restart the device, or restart the computer and hope that new hardware is detected. This is not great.*

[As of November 2021, the `PnPUtil` tool should be used instead of `devcon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil), but even this seems to be for mass operations with device drivers, and not the media in the drive.

---

The closest I could come was

```
RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
```

and even this only opens the "Safely Remove Hardware" dialogue box. You still need to use your mouse to select the media from a list, and click "Stop".